# erase function in vector in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

In vector `v` the numbers are: `2 6 9`

`n` is the number of elements in the array.
`l` and `r` are the indexes (1 based indexing) from which I have to remove the elements from the vectors

```
  vector<int> v(n, 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      int x;
      scanf("%d", &x);
      v[i] = x;
  }
  while (q--)
  {
      int l, r, ans = 0;
      scanf("%d", &l);
      scanf("%d", &r);
      vector<int> v1 = v;
      if (l == r)
          v1.erase(v1.begin() + (l - 1));
      else
          v1.erase(v1.begin() + (l - 1), v1.begin() + r);
```

When I print the vector here I get:

```
6 9 9
```

if `l` is `1` and `r` is `1`, I want to delete the first element only and if `l` is `2` and `r` is `3`, I get `2 6 9`, but I want to delete the elements from 2nd index to 3rd index:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d\n", v1[i]);

rep(i, n)
{
    ans = gcd(ans, v1[i]);
}

printf("%d\n", ans);
}
```

Comment: You should use iterators for your loops, it will help you avoid that kind of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `for` loop that prints the `vector` to `for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)`. You are currently removing elements and then trying to print them anyway, which is **undefined behavior**. Changing the `for` loop corrects this fact.